# Class object in mainwindow.h in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I am trting to open a new window (window with the cubeview view in qt3d application) whenever a button is clicked on the main window.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "cubeview.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    int getid();

public slots:
    void pattern1();

private:
    CubeView *view;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and mainwindow .cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <iostream>
#include "cubeview.h"

int pattern_id;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPushButton *button= new QPushButton("Pattern 1");
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,  SLOT(pattern1()));
    button->show();
    std::cout<<"reached mainwindow constructor"<<std::endl;
    //view= new CubeView;

}
void MainWindow::pattern1()
{
    pattern_id=1;
    view->begin(1);
    view->resize(800, 600);
    view->show();
    std::cout<<pattern_id<<std::endl;
}
int MainWindow::getid()
{
    return pattern_id;
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete view;
}
```

I get a runtime error.

I hope you get what i am trying to do. Whenever i click on the push button, the cubeview view window should show up. What is the mistake i am making?
Where should I define the cubeView class object so that I can use it later.
Can I initialize it as CubeView *view= new CubeView; in a header file.
I tried to write it in the constructor of mainwindow.cpp
but i get a runtime error.

```
#ifndef CUBEVIEW_H
#define CUBEVIEW_H

#include "qglview.h"
#include "qgltexture2d.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QGLSceneNode;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

//! [1]
class CubeView : public QGLView
{
//! [1]
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CubeView(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CubeView();
    void begin(int pattern_id);

public slots:
    void update_action();

protected:
    void paintGL(QGLPainter *painter);

    //! [2]
private:
    QGLSceneNode *cube;
    QGLSceneNode *cursor;
    QGLTexture2D logo;
    QGLTexture2D* texture;
    QGLTexture2D handcursor;

};
//! [2]

#endif


//! [1] constructor, initialize the cube, cursor and camera
CubeView::CubeView(QWidget *parent)
{
    //! [1] draw the paintboard
    QVector3D *cube1_pos= new QVector3D(0.0,0.0,-1.5);
    QGLBuilder builder1;
    builder1 << QGL::Faceted;
    builder1 << QGLCube(3.25);
    cube = builder1.finalizedSceneNode();
    cube->setPosition(*cube1_pos);

    //draw the cursor
    QGLBuilder cursor_builder;
    cursor_builder <<QGL::Faceted;
    cursor_builder <<QGLCube(0.15);
    cursor=cursor_builder.finalizedSceneNode();

    //camera setup
    camera()->setFieldOfView(35);
    camera()->setNearPlane(1);
    camera()->setFarPlane(15);

    //! [2] set texture for cube and cursor
    //QImage image(QLatin1String(":/bluecircle.jpg"));

    handcursor.setImage(QImage(QLatin1String(":/hand.jpg")));
    std::cout<<"constructor called"<<std::endl;


}
```

Comment: Why does this line commented? `//view= new CubeView;` You should allocate memory in constructor

Comment: What's the problem of initializing `CubeView` in the `MainWindow` constructor? On the other hands, you should specify how long the lifetime of `CubeView` you want. It determines where you should initialize it.

Comment: If you don't initialize the `view` pointer it will have an indeterminate value and accessing it in any way except to initialize it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which is probably the most common reasons for crashes).

Comment: "i get a runtime error" - What does your debugger say?

Comment: @cmannett85: it likely says the consequence of a dangling pointer, but yeah, that is not the only issue with this code...

Comment: What does the `CubeView` constructor look like?

Comment: i tried to initialize the view object as mentioned in the mainwindow constructor: view= new CubeView; it gives me a runtime error : Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

Comment: @SunilNair OK, so the problem lies in the class `CubeView`. You should NOT comment it out just for making it able to compile. The run-time error occurs once you press the button (and hence `pattern1()` is called), since you declared a pointer `*view` but it refers nothing. You may now provide the related code of the class `CubeView`.

Comment: Okay, this is what the class cubeview looks like, i have update my question, please find the same above. However, i AM not sure if the problem is with cubeview class: 

     CubeView *view=new CubeView;
    view->begin(4);
    view->resize(800, 600);
    view->show();
    app.exec();
    delete view;

this works perfectly right when written in main.cpp

Comment: The code you posted doesn't initialize the `view` member.

Comment: and this error i get now:
ASSERT failure in QGLPainter: "begin() has not been called or it failed", file painting\qglpainter.cpp, line 1665

Comment: @Mat He did. He just haven't updated the code. Please check the 7th comment.

Comment: @tay: what do I need to update. i initialized the cubeview object in mainwindow constructor. but, it gave me an error as mentioned in my comment above. 

How do I get this to initialize/work?

Comment: What does the `CubeView` constructor look like? Btw, I think you should highlight the issue of `Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.`

Comment: I have mentioned the constructor in my question. please find the edited version above.

Comment: If i do not initialize it, the view object is null but where should i initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found my answer. It has nothing to to do with the definition of the cubeview class constructor. The simple principle is that 
-> we need not create a class object within a loop or the program code crashes.
-> also the view.show if directly put inside a connect slot , will run into the error of an infinite loop. 
Here is the answer.

```html
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <iostream>
#include "cubeview.h"


int pattern_id;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    view=0;

    std::cout<<"reached mainwindow constructor"<<std::endl;
     QPushButton *button= new QPushButton("Pattern 1");
       QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,  SLOT(pattern1()));
       button->show();

   else if(view!=NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"view is already initialized"<<std::endl;
    }


}
void MainWindow::pattern1()
{

  if(view==NULL)
    {
        view=new CubeView;
        view->begin(1);
        view->resize(800, 600);
            view->show();

    }
}
int MainWindow::getid()
{
    return pattern_id;
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
        delete view;
}
```

In this way, the new object window is created if the value is already NULL.